# What's the value of random scale / crop / brightness in image classifier

Tags: tensorflow, classification, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-slim

When we retrain the image classifier layer in Mobilenet, the retrain script allows us to specific several parameters to preprocess the input images:

random_scale
random_crop
random_brightness

I would like to know how to determine these values? I saw in some articles they set random_brightness and random_scale to 30, and random_crop to 0.

Can someone help me to understand these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from this link: https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/docs/tutorials/image_retraining.md

A common way of improving the results of image training is by deforming, cropping, or brightening the training inputs in random ways. This has the advantage of expanding the effective size of the training data thanks to all the possible variations of the same images, and tends to help the network learn to cope with all the distortions that will occur in real-life uses of the classifier. The biggest disadvantage of enabling these distortions in our script is that the bottleneck caching is no longer useful, since input images are never reused exactly. This means the training process takes a lot longer (many hours), so it's recommended you try this as a way of polishing your model only after you have one that you're reasonably happy with.